# How can I capture the item that I clicked on so I can pass it to the API - VueJS & Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I created a sample in codepen with local data. Hoping it still works for you for troubleshooting but I am actually using vuex and an API endpoint that contains the data. I just can't share the API of course.

Anyway, so I am retrieving a collection of application numbers from an API and displaying them in removable chips. The form (not shown in the example) has a field that I can add more applications to this list. That part works fine. My problem is removing an application.

When someone enters an application by mistake, the user can click on the X in the chip to remove it and a manager can come and approve the removal. That part I haven't got to yet but I believe I can do that once I get there as long as I figure this small part first.

In order to remove the right application, I need to capture the one that the user clicked on so I can pass it to the API and then I can pop() it from the state in a mutation. Notice that I am succesfully capturing the right application in a console.log, but I can't capture it in the modal dialog. How can I do this?

```
<div id="q-app">
    <div class="q-pa-md">
        <span v-for="(batch, index) in applications" :key="index">
            <q-chip removable dense outline color="grey-9" @remove="remove(batch.value)">
                {{batch.value}}
            </q-chip>
            <!-- Manager Approval Dialog -->
            <q-dialog v-model="removeApplication" persistent>
                <q-card class="q-pa-lg" style="width: 600px">
                    <q-card-section class="row justify-center items-center">
                        <span class="q-ml-sm">
                            Enter your manager credentials to remove application number: {{batch.value}} from the current batch.
                        </span>
                        <q-form @submit="onSubmit" class="q-gutter-md q-mt-md" style="width: 100%">
                            <div class="row items-start justify-center">
                                <label class="col-4 text-weight-medium form-label">Admin Username:</label>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <q-input 
                                        outlined 
                                        v-model="username" 
                                        color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                        bg-color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                        square 
                                        dense 
                                        type="text" 
                                        id="username">
                                    </q-input>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row items-start justify-center">
                                <label class="col-4 text-weight-medium form-label">Admin Password:</label>
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <q-input 
                                        outlined 
                                        color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                        bg-color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                        square 
                                        dense 
                                        type="password" 
                                        v-model="password">
                                    </q-input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </q-form>
                    </q-card-section>

                    <q-card-actions align="right" class="q-pa-lg">
                        <q-btn label="Decline" color="secondary" v-close-popup></q-btn>
                        <q-btn label="Approve" color="primary" type="submit" v-close-popup></q-btn>
                    </q-card-actions>
                </q-card>
            </q-dialog>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my script

```
new Vue({
    el: '#q-app',
    data() {
        return {
            appsinbatch:{
                applications:[
                    {"value": 741000, "selected": true },
                    {"value": 742000, "selected": true },
                    {"value": 743000, "selected": true }
                ]
            },  
            username: "",
            password: "",
            removeApplication: false,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        applications() {
            return this.appsinbatch.applications;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            //remove the application selected
        },
        remove (applications) {
            console.log(`${applications} has been removed`)
            this.removeApplication = true
        },
    }
})
```

Here is the [**codepen playground**](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/VwLmxzr?editors=1010) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a one-to-one relationship of chip to form. when you click on any of the chips, it toggles the last added form/card. Instead, you should have one form and reuse a single form.

So for this solution, I used a computed and the model. I'm not familiar with quasar, but haven't found a way to toggle visibility based on whether an object is set, and I think it requires use of a model with a boolean value. So I wrapped the card content with a v-if as-well. This was needed, because otherwise `selectedApplication.value` will be rendered even if the `selectedApplication` is null.

```html
<!--
  Forked from:
  https://quasar.dev/vue-components/chip#Example--Outline
-->
<div id="q-app">
    <div class="q-pa-md">
        <q-chip removable dense outline color="grey-9"
                @remove="remove(index)" 
                v-for="(batch, index) in applications"
                :key="index"
                >{{batch.value}}</q-chip>
        <!-- Manager Approval Dialog -->
        <q-dialog v-model="removeApplication" persistent>
            <q-card class="q-pa-lg" style="width: 600px" v-if="selectedApplication">
                <q-card-section class="row justify-center items-center">
                    <span class="q-ml-sm">
                        Enter your manager credentials to remove application number: {{selectedApplication.value}} from the current batch.
                    </span>
                    <q-form @submit="onSubmit" class="q-gutter-md q-mt-md" style="width: 100%">
                        <div class="row items-start justify-center">
                            <label class="col-4 text-weight-medium form-label">Admin Username:</label>
                            <div class="col-8">
                                <q-input 
                                         outlined 
                                         v-model="username" 
                                         color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                         bg-color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                         square 
                                         dense 
                                         type="text" 
                                         id="username">
                                </q-input>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row items-start justify-center">
                            <label class="col-4 text-weight-medium form-label">Admin Password:</label>
                            <div class="col-8">
                                <q-input 
                                         outlined 
                                         color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                         bg-color="cts-purple-faint" 
                                         square 
                                         dense 
                                         type="password" 
                                         v-model="password">
                                </q-input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </q-form>
                </q-card-section>

                <q-card-actions align="right" class="q-pa-lg">
                    <q-btn label="Decline" color="secondary" v-close-popup></q-btn>
                    <q-btn label="Approve" color="primary" type="submit" v-close-popup></q-btn>
                </q-card-actions>
            </q-card>
        </q-dialog>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#q-app',
    data() {
        return {
            appsinbatch:{
                applications:[
                    {"value": 741000, "selected": true },
                    {"value": 742000, "selected": true },
                    {"value": 743000, "selected": true }
                ]
            },
            selection: null,
            username: "",
            password: "",
            removeApplication: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        applications() {
            return this.appsinbatch.applications;
        },
        selectedApplication() {
            if (Number.isInteger(this.selection) && this.selection < this.applications.length){
                this.removeApplication = true;
                return this.applications[this.selection];               
            }
            this.removeApplication = false;
            return false
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            //remove the application selected
        },
        remove (index) {
            this.selection = index;
            var application = this.applications[index]
            this.selection = index;
            console.log(`${application.value} has been removed`)
            this.removeApplication = true
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: Perfect! I can use this and expand further. Thank you man. It's rough being the only one in the team.